# Bluetooth vs USB Mouse Security

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I had a question regarding the use of Wireless mice and security. In general which method of using a wireless mouse is considered more secure, using a mouse with a USB dongle, or using a mouse that can be used directly with a computer that has a wireless card over bluetooth? In the past, I've heard of attacks geared against major PC peripheral brands that use a USB dongle, that can be performed from across the street of the target. On the otherhand I've also heard of Bluebourne and how it can discover a device's bluetooth band and intercept packets. In most cases, which method of connectivity would be considered more secure from an every day, practical standpoint?

Comment: bluetooth is maintained; patched frequently/as needed, others systems may or may not be, and attacks on proprietary devices may be less known but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastille, the company that popularized the attack you talked about in your question, has a site that lists the affected devices.
https://www.mousejack.com/

Bluebourne and what devices are affected is listed here.
https://armis.com/blueborne/

Patch your system and try to select a device that is not on either of those lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly hard nowadays to intercept and attack device bluetooth. It's constantly changing channels as well as it's encrypted and, especially with a mouse, there's a low attack plain with the device. The most they could intercept from your mouse, worst case scenario, is the movements.

Comment: Not that hard. As @Putvi answer says, mousejack is a viable attack that leverages the HID interface to inject keystrokes.

Comment: That's wireless, non-bluetooth, devices. I specifically was talking about bluetooth.

Comment: OP is specifically asking about wireless mouse.

Comment: OP specifically asked about Bluetooth versus wireless mice. 

> using a mouse with a USB dongle, or using a mouse that can be used directly with a computer that has a wireless card over **bluetooth**

Comment: Thanks for this comment Crumblez!